# MySQL IFNULL, Alias and LEFT JOIN result an Unknown column error

Tags: mysql, left-join, alias, mysql-error-1054, ifnull

This is my simplified query:

```
SELECT `student`.`id`, `student`.`firstname`, `student`.`lastname`,
IFNULL(`review`.`score`, '0') AS `adminreview_score`,
`reviewcolor`.`color` AS adminreview_color FROM (`student`)
LEFT JOIN `review` ON `review`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` AND
review.reviewtype_id = 13
LEFT JOIN `reviewcolor` ON `reviewcolor`.`score` = `adminreview_score`
WHERE `student`.`id` > '0'
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'adminreview_score' in 'on clause'
```

Note that there may be no row in `review` table with the situation:

```
`review`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` AND review.reviewtype_id = 13
```

In this situation, I want `adminreview_score` to be set as `0`, and I hope `reviewcolor.color` be `NULL` or empry ()

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  (I replaced the alias with the actual expression.  Note that aliases from the SELECT clause can't be used in the rest of the SQL expression.)

```
SELECT `student`.`id`, `student`.`firstname`, `student`.`lastname`,
IFNULL(`review`.`score`, '0') AS `adminreview_score`,
`reviewcolor`.`color` AS adminreview_color 
FROM (`student`)
    LEFT JOIN `review` ON `review`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` AND review.reviewtype_id = 13
    LEFT JOIN `reviewcolor` ON `reviewcolor`.`score` = IFNULL(`review`.`score`, '0')
WHERE `student`.`id` > '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable, try This

```
set @a:='';

SELECT `student`.`id`, `student`.`firstname`, `student`.`lastname`,
IFNULL(@a:=`review`.`score`, @a:=0),
`reviewcolor`.`color` AS adminreview_color FROM (`student`)
LEFT JOIN `review` ON `review`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` AND
review.reviewtype_id = 13
LEFT JOIN `reviewcolor` ON `reviewcolor`.`score` = @a
WHERE `student`.`id` > '0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I believe that your answer is right, but unfortunately I was not in multi-query enabled mode, so I had to use only One query. Otherwise I would prefer the solution that you suggested.